# cron jobs bring down the server?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am using the paid host Hosting24 to run my website. I got a cron job which execute the following code every 1 minute.

```
<?php 

require_once('connect.php');

for($c = 0; $c < 60; $c=$c+5)
{
    // php to mysql queries SELECT/ UPDATE/ INSERT etc...

    sleep(5);
}

mysql_close($my_connection);}   
?>
```

I tried to use the for loop to allow the script to run for 1 minute. Eventually my script should run for as long as I want it to be because the server will execute it every 1 min.

However, I opened my website for a short while and then I cannot connect to it. I cannot even access my cpanel.

Is my cron job script overheating the system, so the system is down?
How should I set up my cron job script to let it run every 1 min and lasts for 1 min?

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to understand why you're doing this. Assuming your queries take any time at all, I'd think that you would eventually have more than one script running, leaving the queries to get even slower. What are you doing this to your poor DB for?

Comment: I think the system will kill any cron job that ran over 1 min automatically. I am using this cron job script to update my database where a market is simulated. So, the calculation has to be done like every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It's been my experience that cron jobs that need to include files should contain the full path to that file (the CLI environment can differ greatly from the environment inside the web server). Try that and see if it helps.

If not, the next thing you need to do is turn the cron job off and run it from the CLI yourself, using `top` to look at the process usage. See how long it takes for your cron to run.

Comment: Am I right to say that the cron job should run correctly as long as it finishes with in 1 min. For example, the cron job starts at 1:00pm, the script runs for 55 seconds, and the system relaxes for 5 seconds, and the script starts at 1:01pm again?

Comment: That depends on what your script is doing and how busy your system is doing other things. If your DB is serving up a website, and you get a lot of traffic, it could take well over a minute to finish. You really can't plan time frames for scripts because you can never be 100% certain of the environment it's running in.